# How to connect my data model with a view object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, vue.js

I have made class model for my view **the code below** (I'm using nw.js ) :

```
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./../data.sqlite');
class store_model{
        constructor() {
                this.state = {
                        _stmt: null
                }
        }
        readAll() {
                db.each("SELECT * FROM store ", (res, err) => {
                        if (err)
                                console.log(err);
                        else
                                console.log(res);
                });
        }
        read(obj) {

                db.get("SELECT * FROM store WHERE ID =" + obj.id, (res, err) => {
                        if (err)
                                console.log(err);
                        else if (res !== null)
                                console.log(res);
                        else
                                console.log()
                });
        }
        create(obj) {
                try {
                        db.serialize(() => {
                                this.state._stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO store (name,mail) VALUES (?,?)");
                                this.state._stmt.run(obj.name , obj.mail);
                                this.state._stmt.finalize();
                        })
                }
                catch (err) {
                        console.log("There is an error " + err);
                }
        }
        update(obj) {
                db.serialize(() => {
                        this.state._stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE store SET name = COALESCE(?, name) , mail=COALESCE(?,mail) WHERE ID=? ");
                        console.log(obj.name)
                        try {
                        this.state._stmt.run(obj.name, obj.mail, obj.id);
                        }
                        catch (err){
                                console.log(err);
                        }
                        this.state._stmt.finalize();
                        console.log("updated ....");
                })
        }

        delete(obj) {
                this.state._stmt = db.prepare("DELETE FROM store WHERE ID=?");
                this.state._stmt.run(obj.id);
                console.log("supprimer");
        }
}
```

**After Made it I want to pass the response of some of my requests to my view in vue.js the problem I meet is that my requests are in asynchronous function so I can't pass directly my response to my view object because of the scope .I would like someone guide me ( A way to pass the responses of my requests) to be able to transmit my responses to my view object
(My view object have attribute to receive data) .**